# Python dictionary length not as supposed

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a password generator. Here is part of the code I write below:

```
import random

total_length = 12
limit = int(total_length / 4)

special_characters = random.randint(1, limit)
upper_case = random.randint(1, limit)
integers_num = random.randint(1, limit)
sums = special_characters + upper_case + integers_num
lower_case = total_length - sums

integers_sum = [str(a) for a in range(0, 10)]
special_characters_sum = [r'/', r'*', r'-', r'+', r'@']
upper_case_sum = [chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]
lower_case_sum = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)]

pwd_dict = {}
pwd_dict[integers_num] = integers_sum
pwd_dict[special_characters] = special_characters_sum
pwd_dict[upper_case] = upper_case_sum
pwd_dict[lower_case] = lower_case_sum
```

What confused me is that the length of the 'pwd_dict' should be 4, but actually dict length varies from 2 to 4 when runs that code. Hoping someone can help me to figure out why this happens.

I want to create a dict, and use for loops to generate password string (keys are loop times and key.items to be picked ), then sort the string randomly

Comment: Your keys are randomly generated, so may, from time to time, conflict and overwrite each other.

Comment: `random.randint(1, 3)` will yield *1, 2, 3*. There's a pretty high chance that if you call it 3 times, at least 2 of them will be the same.

Comment: @quamrana I think my code is not good enough. I want to know why this happens. Will it related to muti-thread? dict created before keys generated.

Comment: What's the purpose of putting numeric keys into a dict, anyway? Even if not random, perhaps an indexable list of 4 positions would be better

Comment: What would you like `pwd_dict` to be like? What is it purpose? If you did `print(pwd_dict)`, what would you _expect_ to see and how is it different from what it actually prints?

Comment: Why this happens is that entering values into a `dict` with duplicate keys will result in later entries overwriting the last. To keep all values the keys need to be unique.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I want to create a dict, and use for loops to generate password string (keys are loop times and key.items to be picked ), then sort the string randomly.

Comment: @pyhappyer You can run 4 different loops over each list and create strings without needing a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering:

```
special_characters = random.randint(1, limit)
upper_case = random.randint(1, limit)
integers_num = random.randint(1, limit)
```

and

```
pwd_dict = {}
pwd_dict[special_characters] = special_characters_sum
pwd_dict[upper_case] = upper_case_sum
pwd_dict[lower_case] = lower_case_sum
```

It seems that you are using randomly generated integers as your dictionary keys. A python dictionary can only contain unique keys hence in the cases where your keys are the same, the value of a specific key will be replaced instead of a new key/value pair being created.

Furthermore, I don't believe you are interested in using numerical values as keys? You are likely trying to use "lower_case" as a *string* key instead.

Comment: thank you very much! I want to create a dict, and use for loops to generate password string (**keys are loop times and key.items to be picked** ), then sort the string randomly.   maybe when keys are the same, the dict will update the value of that key.  I should write more code and enhance my knowledge.